# Matlab parfor on a database with a user function

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I have a set of images (~10^7) that are contained in a single huge binary file.  I want to read and analyze them efficiently using a function that I already have. Each iteration of that user function `foo` in the code takes about 0.1 sec so it takes days for the code to process the entire database using a simple for loop that reads through the database:

```
... 
for image_number=1:N
     offset_in_bytes = npoints_per_image*element_size*(image_number-1);
     fseek(fid, offset_in_bytes, 'bof'); 
     s=fread(fid, npoints_to_load,'ushort');
     image=reshape(s,nrows,[]);
     [outputs]=foo(image)
end
```

I have optimized the function `foo` as much as I could (vectorized the code when possible, used the right data classes etc). The only thing I haven't done yet is to create a mex version. I thought to use `parfor` for this, but I couldn't get it to work. Tough each image is independent the code above reads data serially so I cant really parallelize it. How can I make this code and database accessible to the `parfor` option? 
thanks

Comment: I've tried that, but `foo` is more or less linear with the number of pixels it receives... So in some occasions I gain in performance, in other there's no difference whatsoever (when feeding it with an image that is composed from multiple images at a time instead of one). I hoped going parallel would really make a difference.

Comment: I did not mean to feed all those images into `foo` at once, but rather loading them and storing them into an array and then feeding them separately into `foo` within a `parfor` loop.

Comment: OK, interesting strategy, so load to memory as much as possible then parfor, then repeat. Isn't there a straight forward way to parfor from the big binary file?

Comment: I do not know how many `fseek`/`fread` calls to one and the same file are possible in parallel. I would estimate their number to be rather small. Furthermore, would the parallel reading of the same file also constitute a bottleneck which limits the efficiency?

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better to split the huge file into several smaller ones and process them in parallel?

Comment: So if I have 6 workers, I should split the file to 6 parts etc? Is it that simple?

Answer (score 0):

To run this loop in parallel effectively, you need to be able to run both the `FREAD` portion and the `foo` portion in parallel. You can check that the `foo` portion runs in parallel by replacing the `FREAD` with a dummy call to something like MATLAB's `RAND`.

Note that `matlabpool` workers run in single-threaded mode. This is particularly important if you're running all your workers on a single machine. If `foo` was able to take good advantage of MATLAB's intrinsic multithreading, then using a `PARFOR` loop instead will probably make things slower.

I suspect that if you have only one large image file, then your filesystem may or may not be able to give you fully parallel access to it. I'm not sure how best to work around that - it's almost certainly dependent on your particular filesystem.

Comment: I tested `foo` alone and it is more efficient using `parfor` in my machine (~70% speed increase for 1000 iterations).But this still doesn't answer the question...

Comment: I don't understand why though - your loop iteration calls `fseek` in such a way that each iteration is independent. Could you clarify why your loop doesn't work as a `PARFOR`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume here that your images are all of the same size, or a size which you know beforehand. That is: you don't have to scan through all previous images to know the size of the current one. If this is not the case the following won't help.

The code provided won't work with parfor because you have multiple workers trying to share the one file handle. Matlab's parallel tools are designed for use with multiple computer clusters, so things like file handles don't get duplicated well.

To make your code work with parfor you need to open and close the file within the loop, like so:

```
parfor image_number=1:N
  fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
  offset_in_bytes = npoints_per_image*element_size*(image_number-1);
  fseek(fid, offset_in_bytes, 'bof'); 
  s=fread(fid, npoints_to_load,'ushort');
  image=reshape(s,nrows,[]);
  [outputs]=foo(image);
  fclose(fid);
end
```

If you find that this adds overhead to your process you may want to use a nested loop and possibly some buffering:

```
chunk_size = ceil(N/10);
parfor i = 0:9
  fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

  %some buffering code here

  %start this iteration of the parfor loop at this image_number
  start_num = 1+(i * chunk_size); 
  end_num = min(N, (i+1) * chunk_size); %and end it at this one

  for image_number=start_num:end_num
    %your code here
  end

  fclose(fid);
end
```

As mentioned by Edric, if you are taking much advantage of vector processing in your foo function then this may not speed it up much, as parfor does make matlab run in single threaded mode.